# Iterate through pages nokogiri get link address

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to get images or image addresses from the website below. It works for the one website that I put below: "http://www.1stsourceservall.com/Category/Accessories".  However--once it's finished with the page--I want it to then click on the next page link and cycle through all 20+ pages.  How would I do that?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.1stsourceservall.com/Category/Accessories"
while (url) do
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    puts doc.css(".productImageMed")
  end

  link = doc.css('.pagination a')
  url = link && link[0]['href'] #=> url is nil if no link is found on the page
end
```

Comment: You want [Mechanize](https://rubygems.org/gems/mechanize).

Comment: And this particular code example is going to throw `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end`.